# The password for the account "..." was not changed on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, password

When trying to update my user account password on macOS Catalina 10.15.1 in the *System Preferences*, under *Users & Groups*, with the *Change Password...* button, I get the error message:

[image: The password for the account "..." was not changed. Your system administrator may not allow you to change your password or there was some other problem with your password. Contact your system administrator for help.]

Of course, I'm sure I entered my login password correctly ;-)

When my system administrator attempts to reset my password using the *Reset Password..." button in the *Users & Groups* system preferences, they get the error message:

[image: Reset password failed]

**What can I do to change my password?**

---

Just a further piece of information that might be related with this issue:
My account was created in a previous version of macOS and I [used my iCloud password to log in and unlock my Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/24/use-icloud-password-as-mac-login-unlock-os-x/). This option has been removed in recent versions of macOS. Moreover, I recently had to change my iCloud password.

Comment: If you try to change the password using `dscl . -passwd <homedir>` where `< homedir >` is the home directory of your user: `/Users/<your user ID>`, does it succeed or do you get an error message?

Comment: @N. Virgo: @jaume’s question goes to you now. As far as I remember, I ended up deleting the old account and creating a new one…